# Best way to count coincidences in an Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, count, array-filter

I have an array of thousands of rows and I want to know what is the best way or the best prectices to count the number of rows in PHP that have a coincidence on it.

In the example you can see that I can find the number of records that match with a range.

I´m thinking in this 2 options:

Option 1:

```
$rowCount = 0;
foreach ($this->data as $row) {
    if ($row['score'] >= $rangeStart && $row['score'] <= $rangeEnd) {
        $rowCount++;
    }
}
return $rowCount;
```

Option 2:

```
$countScoreRange = array_filter($this->data, function($result) {
    return $result['score'] >= $this->rangeStart && $result['score'] <= $this->rangeEnd;
});
return count($countScoreRange);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure someone has to fact check me but I believe the function count() is slower than using $rowCount++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends on what you mean when are you speaking about  **best practices**?
if your idea about best practice is about performance, it can say that there is one tradeoff that you must care about"

```
                                   **speed <===> memory**
```

---

**if you need performance about memory :**

in this way : when you think about performance in iterating an iterable object in PHP, you can Use `YIELD` to create a ***generator function*** , from PHP [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php) :

what is generator function ?

> A generator function looks just like a normal function, except that instead of returning a value, a generator yields as many values as it needs to. Any function containing yield is a generator function.

why we must use generator function ?

> A generator allows you to write code that uses foreach to iterate over a set of data without needing to build an array in memory, which may cause you to exceed a memory limit, or require a considerable amount of processing time to generate.

so it's better to dedicate a bit of memory instead of reserving an array of thousands

[Unfortunately](https://evertpot.com/switching-to-generators/#:%7E:text=Unfortunately%2C%20PHP%20also%20does%20not,including%20array_filter%20%2C%20array_map%20%2C%20etc.):

> Unfortunately, PHP also does not allow you to use the array traversal functions on generators, including array_filter, array_map, etc.

so till here you know if :

1. you are iterating an array
2. of thousands element
3. especially if you use it in a function and the function runs many where.
4. and you care about performance specially in memory usage.

it's highly recommended to use generator functions instead.

---

** but if you need performance about speed :**

the comparison will be about 4 things :

1. `for`
2. `foreach`
3. `array_*` functions
4. array functions (just like `nexT()` , `reset()` and etc.)

The 'foreach' is slow in comparison to the 'for' loop. The foreach copies the array over which the iteration needs to be performed.

but you can do [some tricks](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php) if you want to use it :

For improved performance, the concept of references needs to be used. In addition to this, ‘foreach’ is easy to use.

what about `foreach` and `array-filter` ?
as the previous answer said, also based on this [article](https://www.levijackson.xyz/posts/are-array_-functions-faster-than-loops/) , also [this](https://szymonkrajewski.pl/why-you-should-use-array-functions-instead-of-basic-loops/) : :

> it is incorrect when we thought that array_* functions are faster!

> Of course, if you work on the critical system you should consider this advice. Array functions are a little bit slower than basic loops but I think that there is no significant impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Using foreach is much faster, and incrementing your count is also faster than using `count()`.

I once tested both performance and foreach was about 3x faster than array_filter.

I'll go with the first option.